# Looping in SQL stops abruptly (getting out of memeory)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

Since many have asked me what I am trying to achieve - here is an explanation.

I have to provide a file-feed to a Benfits carrier. The format of the file is
Member1 Record, 
Benefits1 record, 
Benefits2 record etc..
 Member2 Record, 
Benefits1,
Benefits2 and so on.

The way I did this was to get all the member reords and put it in `@member table`. Then I got all the Benefits for all the members and put in the `@Medical_nonHMO table`.

Then I loop through, get the first `@member` record (only one record) and the corresponding `@Medical_nonHMO` records (**which could be more than 1**). Then I get the second member record from `@member` and the corresponding Benefits Records from `@Medical_nonHMO` and so on.

AND Yes, I have checked the value of `@count`.

```
    Select Max(idx) and select count(*) are returning the same value
```

I am not sure how to use cursors to achieve this.

I have around 300 member records and around 400+ benefits records.
It works fine for around 200 records and then abruptly ends and sometimes gives -'Out of Memory' Error.

I have the following loop.

`@member,@medical_nonHMO` are temp. tables that are populated with values.

`@tempcounttable` has 304 rows i.e. the value of `@count`

I am looping through for each member and member benefits

The problem that I am facing, is that even after the query is executed, it has looped through just 174 times.

The 'Out of Loop' doesn't get printed.

BUT this happens only occasionally. Sometimes the loop completely executes and prints 'Out of Loop'

```
DECLARE @tempCounttable TABLE
(
idx smallint Primary Key IDENTITY(1,1),
SSN varchar(9),
SSN_dep varchar(9),
fname varchar(25)
)


INSERT into @tempCounttable 
select SubscriberSSN,   -- Employee SSN
   MemberSSN,   -- Dependent SSN
   FirstName
 from @member

select @count =  MAX(idx) from @tempCounttable
Set @i = 1
While(@i <= @count) 
Begin

  select * from @member
 where SubscriberSSN = (select SSN from @tempCounttable where idx = @i)
and MemberSSN = (select SSN_dep  from @tempCounttable  where idx = @i)
    and FirstName = (select fname from @tempCounttable  where idx = @i)
```

---

```
   select * from @Medical_nonHMO
   where SSN = (select SSN from @tempCounttable where idx = @i)
    and SSN_dependent = (select SSN_dep from @tempCounttable where idx = @i)
     and fname = (select fname from @tempCounttable where idx = @i)
```

---

```
Set @i = @i + 1
select @i           
end

 select 'OUT OF LOOP'
```

Comment: Are you running this from an environment where you are capturing *any* error messages that occur during the procedure?  Are the tables involved being actively modified by other procedures at the same time possibly resulting in some sort of race condition?

Comment: I am actually writing a file-feed for a Benefits carrier. Right now , I am just tesing this in the production enviornment - but no other procudure is being run. In fact, I have another similar loop just before this and it works just perfectly

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking for `select @count = COUNT(idx) from @tempCounttable` not `MAX`?

Comment: MAX works just fine. They have the same value

Comment: Why are you processing this row by row rather than just using joins? If you must do RBAR processing you would be better off using a cursor than all the repeated calls to `select ... from @tempCounttable where idx = @i` anyway.

Comment: What is your data type for `@i`? Perhaps it's out of range.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing what you think you are doing?  select count =  MAX(idx) from tempCounttable gets the MAX(idx) from tempCounttable (not the row count).  How can you be sure tempCounttable table has idx from 1 to MAX(idx).  Circle a was deleted as it is a control character.

Comment: You shoudl not think of looping through records. Whare are you trying to do, we can help you better with a  set-based solutionthat will be fsater if we knew what your really want to do in your loop.

Comment: I have edited my Question. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `@count` is returning 174 rows and not 304 as you are expecting, hence the 174 iterations. Is the table being modified elsewhere? Also, try printing out `@count` before the query is ran each time to give you an indicator.

As a side note, I personally don't understand why this is a while loop?  You could just join `@member` and `@tempCounttable` together since you are just selecting the data:

```
SELECT * FROM @member m
 INNER JOIN @tempCounttable t ON m.memberSSN = t.SSN_dep:
```

You could also filter on fname and SSN.

Comment: @count is 304. I have arelady checked it out. Also, the 'Out of loop' is not getting printed. The reason I need the loop is because the file feed requires this format.Memeber Record1, Benefit1, Benefit2, Member Record2,Benefit1,Bendift2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your assertion that @count is correct with the following

```
select @count =  MAX(idx) from @tempCounttable
Set @i = 1
While(@i <= @count) 
Begin
  select SSN from @tempCounttable where idx = @i
  Set @i = @i + 1
  select @i           
end
select 'OUT OF LOOP'
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helped. @count was not getting the correct value.

Comment: Sorry! It did work once. But now again, I'm have the same problem

Comment: Your problem is @i is NOT real data.  To assume the idx will have every value from 1 to MAX(idx) is just plain sloppy.  People are tying to help you and you are just not listening.  The solutions starts with throwing out your current code.

Comment: Something that  I tried out was Set @i = 200 and execute loop. Works fine. Then I slowing started decreasing the initial value of i and when Set @i=74, it stopped working.  Is there a way to release the memory or something equivalent.

Comment: How many ways can I say this?   At i is NOT a real value!  You should NOT but using at i.  I highly suspect that in  at tempCounttable there is no idx with a value of 74.

Comment: Sorry!I am a bit lost here. Before looping, I am doing a `Select * from @tempCounttable` and I can see all the rows and idx values starting from 1 to 304.

Comment: See and use are not the same thing.  If you want the value of idx then get the value of idx (not a count - or iteration on the count).